# local apt mirror and point in time release

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I am searching for a way to provide a point in time release of a local Ubuntu mirror and came across [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) and [repo-snapshots](https://github.com/Chatham/repo-snapshots). Both look promising, where `aptly` seems to win in regards to features and might be the solution in the future.

- `repo-snapshot` seems to hardlink the `.deb` files into different folders which opens up a lot of different `pool` and `dists` roots which I think makes things confusing.
- `aptly` being more abstract seems to merge the different packages into a single `pool` and providing different `dists` folders/configurations to access the corresponding files. So that looks really promising

For now, I was thinking if it would be possible to just copy the corresponding `dists` folder containing all the metadata about the selection of the packages at a given time to and use that as `suite` in my `sources.list`.
To illustrate this, being in the root of the mirror, there is a `pool` directory containing all the `.deb` files, and a `dists` folder containing all the metadata needed to access the `.deb` files.

```
apt-mirror@xenial:~/mirror/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu$ ls -l                 
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 6 apt-mirror apt-mirror 4096 Apr 21 10:42 dists
drwxrwxr-x 3 apt-mirror apt-mirror 4096 Apr 21 09:05 pool

apt-mirror@xenial:~/mirror/ubunut-mirror/ubuntu$ ls -l dists/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 apt-mirror apt-mirror 4096 Apr 21 09:05 xenial
```

Could one now just copy the `dists/xenial` folder to e.g. `dists/xenial_2018-04-22` and use that as the `suite` in a `sources.list` file to reference a package selection at a given time?

```
deb http://localmirror/mirror/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu xenial_2018-04-22 main
```

A quick test did the trick but I am not sure if am missing something or any problems could occur in the future. Sure, you have to take care that `.deb` files are not deleted from `pool/*`.